# Golf HCP Calculator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, for-loop

I am working on a program in ASP.NET MVC where my goal is to make an golf scorecard.

In golf every player have an handicap which give them a number of extra strokes on each golf course they play. these number are then distributed over the 18 holes depending on the index on the hole (how hard it is) So for example if you get 25 extra strokes you get one stroke on hole 1-18 and then one extra on index hole 1-7 (so you have two extra strokes on these holes).

My scorecard is presented in the view with an field next to the hole number where i want to present how many extra strokes you have on this hole. So now i want to make a function that distribute these extra strokes.

My idea for the functions is that i pass in the players scorecard and the number of strokes as a parameter and then in some kind of for loop distribute the numbers of strokes over the 18 hole. And then return the list so i can present it in the view.

Anyone who can help me how to write this function?

/ Mike

This is how i started but got stuck..

```
public static List<Result> DistributeStrokes (int stroke,List<Result>MyList)

{

for(int i=0; i< MyList.count; i--;)

  {

   //do some code to add the strokes on the list 

  }

   return MyList;

 }
```

This is my class

```
public Class Result

{

 public int Id {get;set}

 public int Stroke{get;set}  //number of strokes on the hole

 public int Score {get;set}   //number of extra stroke on the hole

 public int Point {get;set}

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us what you've got, tell us what's not working and I'm sure someone will be able to help.

Comment: updated my comment now  Andy Lamb

Comment: Is the number of holes fixed? Do we always have exactly 18 holes? And also if you have 15 strokes the logic is that you got one extra hole for holes 1 to 15 (15 included excluded?). Sorry but I don't know the rules of golf.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of the below code should help, even if it's not 100% correct (I'm replying from my phone). Using the modulus operator to loop through your list, incrementing the result stroke while decrementing the stroke parameter.

```
int index = 0;
while (stroke > 0) 
{
    stroke--;
    MyList[index].Stroke++;
    index = (index + 1) % MyList.Count;
}
```

You'll also want to consider handling the case where the list is empty, etc.